# How to Save Entity With Non-Identity Primary Column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

I have a member class:

```
[Table("members")]
public partial class Member
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String lang { get; set; }
    public Boolean activated { get; set; }
    public String gender { get; set; }
    public String first_name { get; set; }
    public String middle_name { get; set; }
    public String last_name { get; set; }
}
```

and a member_activation class:

```
[Table("member_activation")]
public class MemberActivation
{
    [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Int64 member_id { get; set; }
    public String token { get; set; }
}
```

member_activation.member_id is a foreign key from members.id.

This is my DbContext:

```
public class SMADbContext : DbContext
{
    public SMADbContext() : base("SMADB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SMADbContext>(new NullDatabaseInitializer<SMADbContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MemberActivation> MemberActivations { get; set; }
}
```

When I try...

```
public bool tester()
    {
        var db = new SMADbContext();
        var memberActivation = new MemberActivation();
        memberActivation.member_id = 10150;
        memberActivation.token = "hello";
        db.MemberActivations.Add(memberActivation);
        if(db.SaveChanges())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I get an error message saying:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'member_id', table 'dbname.dbo.member_activation'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

Anybody know of a way that I can save my `member_activation` row?

Comment: I feel like there is something we are missing here, there is nothing wrong with the code you have posted.

Comment: @DavidG There is something wrong, but I just figured it out. I had to add a data annotation on the member_id like in my edit

Comment: [Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Answer (score 0):

If your query is "How to Save Entity With Non-Identity Primary Column?".

Then answer is you can't. There must be a primary key in table(entity).

But Actually in your code, i can see the key.